# While loop repeating too many times

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm a first year in Computer Science Engineering, and I'm currently taking a Java programming course. It's the first programming language I've ever tried learning and I'm completely stuck. I had to design a program for class that takes a credit card number input from the user and determines whether or not it is valid. I've somehow messed up my loops, and now the whole thing keeps repeating at least 5 times more than I need it to. How could I fix this? It's due by 3:00 and I'm freaking out. Here is my code:

```
package osu.cse1223;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project07 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit):");
    String cardNumber = in.nextLine();

    int length = cardNumber.length();

    if (length != 16 && length > 0) {
        System.out.print("ERROR! Number MUST have exactly 16 digits");
    }
    else if (length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
    else {
        char checkDigitChar = cardNumber.charAt(15);
        int checkDigit = Character.getNumericValue(checkDigitChar);

        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < 16) {
            char digit = cardNumber.charAt(pos);
            int number = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
            int doubled = number * 2;
            pos = pos + 2;
            int sum = 0;
            if (doubled > 9) {
                String sub = Integer.toString(doubled);
                char one = sub.charAt(0);
                char two = sub.charAt(1);
                int numOne = Character.getNumericValue(one);
                int numTwo = Character.getNumericValue(two);
                int doubleAdjusted = numOne + numTwo;
                sum = sum + doubleAdjusted;
            }
            else {
            }
            int newPos = 1;
            int newSum = 0;
            while (newPos < 16) {
                char digitForSum = cardNumber.charAt(newPos);
                int individualNum = Character.getNumericValue(digitForSum);
                newPos = newPos + 2;
                newSum = individualNum + newSum;
            }

            int total = sum + newSum;
            String subTwo = Integer.toString(total);
            char onesPlace = subTwo.charAt(1);
            int ones = Character.getNumericValue(onesPlace);
            int realCheckDigit = 10 - ones;

            System.out.println("Check digit should be: " + realCheckDigit);
            System.out.println("Check digit is: " + checkDigit);

            if (checkDigit == realCheckDigit) {
                System.out.println("Number is valid");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Number is not valid");
            }
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger what do you see? You have two loops nested inside each other. WHich one loops too many times?

Comment: It looks like they're both looping too many times..

Comment: I suggest using an IDE to format your code or pay close attention to where your loops start and end. If you code still has bugs, a debugger is the fastest way to understand where your bug is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not ending your first loop in the right place.

```
int doubleAdjusted = numOne + numTwo;
sum = sum + doubleAdjusted;
}
else {
}
}// ADD THIS TO END THE FIRST WHILE LOOP
```

And remove a `}` from the bottom of the code.

Comment: Can you please explain how does this solve the problem?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! That solved the loop issue, haha. But now the console isn't showing the correct answer like it was doing before. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the correct answer and what is it showing now?

Comment: With this input (5457623898234113) it should say that the check digit should have been 3, and that it was 3. But after I changed the loops it started saying random answers like should have been 4 and was 3, that sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

This loop repeats 8 times, but in fact it should be stoped after the first cycle. There are two ways to do this. First, you can add "break;" in the end of the last cycle. Second, you can not use "while (pos < 16) {}" loop at all. Both variants will give you the same result.

Here is the variant:

```
public class Various {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int sum = 0;
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit):");
String cardNumber = in.nextLine();

int length = cardNumber.length();

if (length != 16 && length > 0) {
    System.out.print("ERROR! Number MUST have exactly 16 digits");
}
else if (length <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
else {
    char checkDigitChar = cardNumber.charAt(15);
    int checkDigit = Character.getNumericValue(checkDigitChar);

    int pos = 0;
//        while (pos < 16) {
        char digit = cardNumber.charAt(pos);
        int number = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
        int doubled = number * 2;
//            pos = pos + 2;

        if (doubled > 9) {
            String sub = Integer.toString(doubled);
            char one = sub.charAt(0);
            char two = sub.charAt(1);
            int numOne = Character.getNumericValue(one);
            int numTwo = Character.getNumericValue(two);
            int doubleAdjusted = numOne + numTwo;
            sum = sum + doubleAdjusted;
        }

        else {
        }

        int newPos = 1;
        int newSum = 0;
        while (newPos < 16) {
            char digitForSum = cardNumber.charAt(newPos);
            int individualNum = Character.getNumericValue(digitForSum);
            newPos = newPos + 2;
            newSum = individualNum + newSum;
        }

        int total = sum + newSum;
        String subTwo = Integer.toString(total);
        char onesPlace = subTwo.charAt(1);
        int ones = Character.getNumericValue(onesPlace);
        int realCheckDigit = 10 - ones;

        System.out.println("Check digit should be: " + realCheckDigit);
        System.out.println("Check digit is: " + checkDigit);


        if (checkDigit == realCheckDigit) {
            System.out.println("Number is valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number is not valid");
        }
//            break;
//        }
       }

    }
  }
```